# Pandas: loop through rows and check if row is the same as previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
```

I want to loop through it, and do something if a row as the same value as the last row.

Something like this:

```
for row, index in df.iterrows():
    if row == previous row: # that's the line I'm looking for
        print("ok")
```

Comment: do you want just for printing or are you storing the values? you can try `df.eq(df.shift())`  if you want a series back

Comment: No just printing. I don't need to store the value, just compare in a loop.

Comment: do the same as I suggested using `shift` : `s = df.eq(df.shift())` then 
`for _,r in s.iterrows(): 
    if r.iat[0] : print('ok')
    else: print('not ok')`